# Comment blocks around JSON responses

Tags: security, json

I've noticed that some web applications return AJAX responses with JSON data embedded within a comment block.  For example, this would be a sample response:

```
/*{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "address": {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY",
     "postalCode": 10021
 },
 "phoneNumbers": [
     "212 555-1234",
     "646 555-4567"
 ]} */
```

What is the benefit of embedding the JSON data in a comment block?  Is there some sort of security exploit which is avoided by doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's done to avoid a third party site hijacking your data using a `<script>` tag and overriding the `Object` constructor to grab the data as it is built.

When the JSON data is surrounded by comments, it no longer is directly executable via a `<script>` tag, and thereby "more secure".

See the PDF at http://www.fortifysoftware.com/servlet/downloads/public/JavaScript_Hijacking.pdf for more information (with examples)

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Could you please provide another reference?