# jQuery service response showing in firebug but not getting in success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I facing an issue when accessing the service url using browser it runs and show json result on browser like this.

```
  /*-secure-{"statusCode":200,"errors":
  ],"isSuccessful":true,"statusReason":"OK","Envelope":
 {"Body":{"GetStoresByZipcodeResponseElement":
 {"ns1":"http:\/\/abc.com\/intg\/ws\/\/provider","status":"statusCode":"000","statusDescription":"Success"}}*/"
```

but when I hitting that url using jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false, // must be set to false
        success: function (data, success) {
           console.log(" success "+ JSON.stringify(success));
           console.log(" data " +JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error :function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) { 
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
        },

        complete: function (jqxhr, textStatus ){
        console.log( "complete: " + JSON.stringify(jqxhr)+" "+ textStatus );
        }
    });
```

its showing me the response in firebug but even it come to ajax success function and for data its saying undefined.

after change 'script' with 'json' return this:

```
Request Failed: error,
complete: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","responseJSON":null,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} error
```

JSON Response and Response tab view in Firebug
[image: JSON Response in Firebug]
[image: Response in Firebug]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `dataType` "json" instead of "script" and use the `complete` and/or `error` callbacks to debug the problem.

Comment: @Stefan I edited my code in post. after add complete and error its return this output on console with 'script' dataType "success "success"
data undefined
complete: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"} success"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these callback functions and find out what "data" is.

```
success: function(data, success) {
  console.log("success", arguments);
  console.log("data", typeof data, data); // Verify the response
},
error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) { 
  console.log("error", arguments);
},
complete: function(jqxhr, textStatus) {
  console.log("complete", arguments);
}
```

Also, why not disable the cache while debugging? `cache: false`.

It seems like you´re trying to request some [secured JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019101/896341) data as the response is not valid JSON and that is probably why jQuery can´t parse it.

If neccessary, it would be possible to write a custom [`dataFilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to trim and parse the response.

```
dataFilter: function(data, type) {

  if (type === 'json') {
    // TODO: Parse the custom format by removing the comments
    // and then parsing what is expected to be valid JSON.
    return $.parseJSON(data);
  }

  return data;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You are trying to make a cross-domain request and should be using [JSONP](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/), if the service provider supports it as you are limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: thanks for this help but still facing the issue finding typeof is data in dataFilter where its still showing me undefined and for type is showing script.

Comment: The data is neither a valid script or JSON. Where from are you trying to fetch it?

Comment: [fetching url](http://mobileservices.tbccorp.com/worklight/invoke?parameters=[33412]&adapter=StoreWebServices&procedure=GetStoresByZipcode)

Comment: Thanks Stefan your reply any idea what need to be fixed on server side for this cross-domain issue.